# Odoo 16 custom module could not be installed

Tags: odoo

> ****My Code in views:****
>
> ```
> <!--account account type form view inherit-->
> <record id="view_account_type_from" model="ir.ui.view">
>     <field name="name">view.account.type.form</field>
>     <field name="model">account.account.type</field>
>     <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_type_form"/>
>     <field name="arch" type="xml">
>     <xpath expr="//field[@name='include_initial_balance']" position="after">
> ```

> **Error on install:
> odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while
> parsing....../odoo_account_type_menu/views/account_type_menu.xml:9,
> somewhere inside strong text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view `account.account.type` model has been removed in Odoo 16, and it's replaced with the below selection field in [`account.account`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/account/models/account_account.py#L43) model.

So you can inherit account.account model and override the selection field.

```
    account_type = fields.Selection(
        selection=[
            ("asset_receivable", "Receivable"),
            ("asset_cash", "Bank and Cash"),
            ("asset_current", "Current Assets"),
            ("asset_non_current", "Non-current Assets"),
            ("asset_prepayments", "Prepayments"),
            ("asset_fixed", "Fixed Assets"),
            ("liability_payable", "Payable"),
            ("liability_credit_card", "Credit Card"),
            ("liability_current", "Current Liabilities"),
            ("liability_non_current", "Non-current Liabilities"),
            ("equity", "Equity"),
            ("equity_unaffected", "Current Year Earnings"),
            ("income", "Income"),
            ("income_other", "Other Income"),
            ("expense", "Expenses"),
            ("expense_depreciation", "Depreciation"),
            ("expense_direct_cost", "Cost of Revenue"),
            ("off_balance", "Off-Balance Sheet"),
        ],
        string="Type", tracking=True,
        required=True,
        compute='_compute_account_type', store=True, readonly=False, precompute=True,
        help="Account Type is used for information purpose, to generate country-specific legal reports, and set the rules to close a fiscal year and generate opening entries."
    )
```

Comment: What to inherit in odoo 16 please ? I wanted to rename account types in v16 and need this custom module..... (Is account.view_account_type_form replaced with other view type or what?)

Comment: ```account.account.type``` removed in Odoo 16.0 and replaced with selection field in ```account.account``` model. see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Waleed, This and the support you made was very important.